# Cant load second template into My Django project

Tags: python, django

i'm a beginner in `Django` and need a little help

My application's layout is as following

```
adray/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    migrations/
        __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py 
    static
    Templates/
       adray/
         index.html
         happen.html
```

I'm trying to load two html file's into two different methods: index & request, while index works, request doesn't, it seems like the `loader.get_template` method doesn't work for the second time, and i get the following exception:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 3269: invalid start byte
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#from adray.models import Item 
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader,Template 

def index(request):
        template = loader.get_template('adray/index.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render())

    def happen(request):
        template = loader.get_template('adray/happen.html') # this second load doesn't work!
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

When i change the happen method into:

```
def happen(request):
           # template = loader.get_template('adray/happen.html') 
            return HttpResponse(request)
```

It works fine (happen.html do exist, checked that!)

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from adray import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index),
   url(r'^happen/$', views.happen),
]
```

Comment: What happens when you change happen.html into index.html in your happen view?

Comment: It works, are you suggesting that there is some thing wrong with my happen.html? when i open it as stand alone, it works, is it possible that because it has form and buttons it doesn't work?

Comment: Could be your template file is in the wrong encoding. Have a look at this page: http://blog.p3infotech.in/2013/fixing-template-unicodedecodeerror-in-django/

Comment: Yes seems to be it, please post it as an answer, ill take it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be your template file is in the wrong encoding. Have a look at this page: http://blog.p3infotech.in/2013/fixing-template-unicodedecodeerror-in-django/